# How to make CPP core functions friends of my class

Tags: c++

Help me please. I want to make my class for range statement compliant. That means I need the required overloaded operators defined and define begin and end functions.

What I don't want is for anything else except for range to be able to use the defined begin and end functions . Simply because it wouldn't be needed otherwise.

How can I make range for statement a friend of my class?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you [edit] your question to make it clearer, perhaps also by adding some code which has your class and functions you need to make `friend`? Better yet, it might be better to include [mcve] which demonstrates your problem, since this may simply be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (you may be asking about _Y_ but you should be asking about _X_). I hope this is clear.

Comment: @Tas Sounds like he wants to allow some built-in methods to use `MyClass::begin()` and `MyClass::end()`, but not allow anything else to use them, so he doesn't want to make them public.

Comment: Specifically, the OP wants the class to be usable in a range for, but doesn't want to expose `begin()` and `end()`

Comment: Why is it a problem to expose said methods ?

Comment: “Wouldn’t be needed” is not the same as “must be prevented”.

Comment: Great! You guys understand my question. I think the idea of a class is to clearly express to the user what is meant to. Or easily, how to use it meaningfully; unlike lower level style with many functions and not know which ones you should actually be using .

Answer (score 2):

It’s not possible to restrict the use of `begin`/`end` to the range-`for` statement, since it is defined as equivalent to a [certain compound statement](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#1) that looks them up without any special access permission.  The closest you can get is to make them [hidden friends](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#3), but that doesn’t hide them when their argument is of the class type in question!

Comment: So I have a class, PlotCircle, with range and data members which could make use of for range statement instead of for statements.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you're trying to shoe-horn things into for loops that don't necessarily make sense to be used in for loops. If I have a class called 'PlotCircle', the name would not really suggest to me that iterating over it would make any sense, as opposed to just calling a function such as 'PlotCircle.plot()' which internally iterates over the data.